# Fluent Operator Configurations to get http inputs on to elasticsearch

Tags: http, elasticsearch, operator-keyword, elasticsearch-5, fluent

I have successfully

- Deployed Fluent operator and fluentd statefulset using the operator (01-fluentd-setup.yaml) (Ref:
  https://github.com/fluent/fluent-operator)
- Configured http plugin for input in fluentd
- Configured output to Elastic search (logs attached)
- curl to http endpoint of fluentd and got 200 OK

...but:

- fluentd pod logs show a different configuration loaded each time which I have not specified in 02-fluentd-cluster-cfg-output-es.yaml
- The successful curl POST is actually going to @type null instead of to elastic search

Questions:

1. How can I get rid of unwanted match tag?
2. I wanted to get the JSON POSTs on fluent http endpoint to be delivered to Elasticsearch. Where can I configure?

Fluentd pod logs:

[image: Fluentd pod logs]

Curl output:

[image: Curl output]

02-fluend-cluster-cfg-output-es.yaml:

[image: 02-fluend-cluster-cfg-output-es.yaml]